# Display all categories for a product on product details page

Tags: magento-2.1, category, product-attribute

In my Magento 2.1 store, I need to display the categories that a product belongs to, in the attributes area of the page (Manufacturer, SKU, etc).

In my magento 1 store, I did this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531702/magento-display-all-categories-on-product-view-page-with-parent-categories/9533005

So if a product is in two categories, they might be displayed as follows:

```
Root Cat > Sub Cat > Sub Sub Cat 1
Root Cat > Sub Cat > Sub Sub Cat 2
```

With each category level being clickable to go to that category.

How do I do the same thing in Magento 2.1?

Comment: Trying to get this to work in Magento 2.4.6.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this first let's create new tab for category display.

1. Create file catalog_product_view.xml in the

> app/design/frontend/{vender name}/{theme name}/Magento_Catalog/layout

In the file write the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="categoryinfo.tab" as="categoryinfo" template="product/view/category_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Category</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. create the file category_info.phtml in the path

> app/design/frontend/{vender name}/{theme name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view.

In the file you can write any content like i have call all categories of this product.

```
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

    $categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');

    $appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $productId = $block->getProduct()->getId(); // YOUR PRODUCT ID
    $product = $productRepository->getById($productId);

    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

    $categories = $categoryCollection->create()
                                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                     ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $name = $category->getName();
        $parentCategories = $category->getParentCategories();
     foreach($parentCategories as $parent){
       $parentname = $parent->getName();
       echo '<a href="'.$parent->getUrl().'" title="'.$parentname.'" alt="'.$parentname.'">';
       echo '<div>'.$parentname.'</div>';
       echo '</a>'; echo ' > ';
    }
echo '<a href="'.$category->getUrl().'" title="'.$name.'" alt="'.$name.'">';
echo '<div>'.$name.'</div>';
echo '</a>';
  if($category->hasChildren()) {
     $subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
     foreach($subcategories as $subcat){
       $subname = $subcat->getName();
       echo ' > ';
      echo '<a href="'.$subcat->getUrl().'" title="'.$subname.'" alt="'.$subname.'">';
       echo '<div>'.$subname.'</div>';
      echo '</a>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I already had the display side of the code worked out from my Magento1 store, but the creation of the collections was the problem for me. Your code gave me the answer, and it works well! Rather oddly though, my old code to output the last item in the category breadcrumbs is no longer needed. Perhaps the "parent categories" also contains the category, and not just the parents, because everything is output correctly. Anyway - thank you!! :-)